# make dialogflow repeat the user

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to make the dialogflow repeat the user input

For example when the user types
"Hello I'm Bob"

I want the API to reply me with

"Welcome Bob."

So I'm trying to create a variable but I have no idea how this is possible in Dialogflow. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, Bob is name for your sentence so when intent gets triggered you will get default `sys@first-name`.

So from the backed service, you can send whatever you want to send with messages.

suppose the parameter name is the `username`.

```
let response = `Welcome ${username}`
```

and send it.